# Dynamically create javascript values with given data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build an dynamic ajax function that saves `data-xxx`-values of elements to process the data. However I want to shorten this code which takes values depending on the ajax-request I want to process:

```
var data_form = $(element).attr('data-form');
var data_index = $(element).attr('data-index');
var data_hide_error = $(element).data('hide-error');
var data_disable_blur = $(element).data('disable-blur');
var data_hide_success = $(element).data('hide-success');
```

in a way that I only have one or two lines of code where I check which data-values are given in the element and if there is one data-value, I want to create a variable with that exact name.

For example: I click on this anchor `<a href="#" data-index="1" data-form="#registerForm">send</a>` and my function would create the variables `var data_index = 1;` and `var data_form = '#registerForm';` automatically.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please elaborate. Your question is not clear. Also you have `$(element).attr('data-form');` when `$(element).data('form');` will suffice

Comment: I know, that was just an example. Also I stated my question very precisely. I want to save the data-attribute-values in a javascript variable if there is a data-attribute-value of a specific data-attribute. And this variable should have the same name as the data-attribute.

Comment: You can use `$(element).data();` to get all `data-` attributes from element as object

Comment: Beat me by 13 seconds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this: Using .data() will return all data-attributes in one object to use in the function that you call

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-index="1" data-form="#registerForm">send</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this.